# Why would my random forest create a model that has a worse F1 than one of the features has on its own?

Tags: random-forest

I am trying to detect a rare event (eventA) using a random forest in R. One of my features is itself an event (eventB). If eventB happens it should cause eventA, so it is a really good predictor. However, this is not the only way to cause eventA, and the eventB feature is actually incorrect about half of the time. If i predict that eventA happens every time eventB happens, I get about 30% recall and 50% precision. If I feed eventB into a random forest model with a few other predictors I end up with lower recall and precision from the model. Why does this happen? Is the only explanation that the trees where eventB isn't selected in the feature set are so much worse at predicting eventA that the model ends up worse overall?

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis makes sense to me; the next step would be to actually check on your data if your hypothesis is correct.

So, I would go ahead and fit a random forest (RF) model that always splits on eventB. One way would be to subset and only keep the trees in your ensemble that split on eventB in the first split. Another way of doing this is to first split your data into two parts, the ones with eventB and the ones without. Then fit a separate RF for each of the two groups; at prediction time you feed your observation into the RF corresponding to eventB = 1 or eventB  = 0.

What is the precision and recall of this model? If this also performs worse, then we can revisit other possible reasons (perhaps a start then would be to check how variable your recall/precision are, say, if you bootstrap the training data).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This makes sense as a next step, however I think option 1 would be fairly hard for me to implement in R and I'm not totally clear why option 2 would work. So I would fit an RF on only the data where eventB = 1, and then use that predict for my greater dataset, but how does that guarantee that the RF will use eventB as a split when making the prediction?

Comment: No, I said that you should fit two random forests (not one), one for data with eventB=1, one with eventB=0. When times comes to predict, you feed it to either one depending on eventB=1 or eventB=0. This is equivalent to forcing *all trees* to first split on eventB. Does this make sense?

Comment: Oh yup that makes perfect sense. Thanks for clarifying!